# How to avoid restarting nginx to renew letsencrypt certificate?

Tags: cron, nginx

I have installed a Nginx server to host my website, and added HTTPS with LetsEncrypt.

The problem is every time the certificate expire, my site become inaccessible and I need to manually restart the service using
So every two months or so I am forced to manually do a:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

I tried automating that several time already but failed. My last attempt was using this:

```
sudo crontab -e 

0 0,12 * * * letsencrypt renew >/dev/null 2>&1 
1 0,12 * * * root /etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

Is this the wrong way?
How can I validate this job works without waiting my site to be inacessible again?

Comment: Your cron syntax is wrong. You are editing a user crontab, therefore no username must be given. Please remove the `root` from the second crontab line.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to add a cron job to go off every 3 months, this is typically done when using certbot in the first place.

Let’s Encrypt’s certificates are only valid for ninety days. This is to encourage users to automate their certificate renewal process. The certbot package we installed takes care of this for us by adding a renew script to /etc/cron.d. This script runs twice a day and will automatically renew any certificate that’s within thirty days of expiration.

To test the renewal process, you can do a dry run with certbot:

```
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

If you see no errors, you’re all set. When necessary, Certbot will renew your certificates and reload Nginx to pick up the changes. If the automated renewal process ever fails, Let’s Encrypt will send a message to the email you specified, warning you when your certificate is about to expire.

Also, you should NOT have to restart Nginx unless you are moving the certificate around, it should pick up where you left off once the new certificate is made. 
When the SSL Certificate renewed is it being saved in the same spot?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really know where the certificate is saved, I set up https two or three years ago. I will try to install certbot and see if it works correctly. Should I delete my other crontab jobs?

Comment: Shouldn't need to, if you follow https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04 Should be pretty lickity split.

Answer (score -3):

Just deploy docker container with this command to install letencrypt ssl certificates

```
docker run \
--name=letsencrypt \
--cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
-e PUID=1000 \
-e PGID=1000 \
-e TZ=Europe/London \
-e URL=your.domain.com \
-e VALIDATION=http \
-e EMAIL=****@gmail.com \
-e PROD=true \
-p 443:443 \
-p 80:80 \
-v /path/to/appdata/config:/config \
-d \
--restart unless-stopped \
linuxserver/letsencrypt
```

Now auto renew certificates with the script available in /app/le-renew.sh
Install crontab to do this

```
0 0 1 * * sudo docker exec letsencrypt /app/le-renew.sh
```